# Why is my C++ program outputting a different number for conversion of meters to feet?

Tags: c++, netbeans

So i am writing a C++ program to convert meters to feet. The program does compline. However, when i set the value of feet = 3.279 and entered 3.25 for meters. The answer comes back as 9.837. Can someone tell me why this may be happening? 
(code below)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
int meters; 
int feet;
feet = 3.279 * meters; 

cout << "Enter Meters to be converted to feet: "; 
cin >> meters;

cout << meters * 3.279 << " feet " << endl;

}
```

Comment: Because `meters` and `feet` are integers.

Comment: because you're using integers as variables, ie numbers with to fractional part.

Comment: [What is an integer?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)

Comment: Use floating point types to preserve the fractional parts of the numbers. `double meters; double feet;`

Comment: Required reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: It's not possible to store `3.25` in a variable of type `int`.   When reading, it will read a value `3`, and stop leaving the `.25` in the stream's buffer waiting to be read.

Comment: It should also be noted that you are calculating `feet` **before** you ever input `meters`.  Have you turned compiler warnings off?  Or are you not reading them?  Warnings are your first step to finding problems in your code.

Comment: [Try inspecting your variables](https://www.ideone.com/19S0wt).

Answer (score 1):

[Integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) are whole numbers. When a non-whole number is assigned to an integer in C++ everything past the decimal is ignored.

```
int x = 1.123; // x = 1
int y = 1.999; // y = 1
```

Furthermore, this program uses `meters` before it has been assigned a value on the following line

```
feet = 3.279 * meters;
```

But `feet` is also never used after this assignment.

The only portion of code that is really being used is

```
cin >> meters;
cout << meters * 3.279 << " feet " << endl;
```

When you input `3.25` for `meters` the value as an integer becomes `3`. The  calculation on the following line therefore becomes `3 * 3.279` which does in fact equal `9.837`.